Do any scriptures mention Ayudha Puja?
Most of us celebrate Ayudha Pooja at the ninth day of Navaratri. But, does any scriptures mention about Ayudha Puja? If yes, which scriptures mention it?

Quoting Hemadri & Nirnayamrta, Nirnayasindhu mentions lauhabhisarika karma on Asvina sukla navami. On this day, after worshipping the forefathers, the rajapurohita was to perform homa, anoint the weapons (khadga, knife, cutlass, javelin, shield), implements of battle (war banner, war drum, war trumpet) & royal insignia (umbrella, chourie, horse, flag, elephant, royal sceptre, throne) alongside officiating the sacrifice of an animal (preferably buffalo) to Bhagavati Durga by the king. This is the prototype of ayudha puja performed in certain parts of India.

However, the Ayudha Puja seen nowadays is done by the commoners & doesn't involve homa & pashubali. It is of 2 types - those performed in & around South India which involve anointing tools & implements like cars, scooters, computers, machinery & artisans' tools (a similar ceremony is performed in North India while venerating Visvakarma) and the modern ones performed by certain organisations anointing all sorts of weapons including firearms, which is clearly borrowed from the Sikh version.
